# Чем плох этот код

Tags: php, utf-8

Функция subsrt для работы с UTF.. чем она плоха?

```
 function utf8_substr($str,$start)
    {
       preg_match_all("/./su", $str, $ar);

       if(func_num_args() >= 3) {
           $end = func_get_arg(2);
           return join("",array_slice($ar[0],$start,$end));
       } else {
           return join("",array_slice($ar[0],$start));
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем плох [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)
?

Comment: Ничем не плох, но вопрос не в том.

Comment: Хотя нет, чем она плоха можно посмотреть на скрине http://floomby.ru/content/MmNkrouAVU

Comment: Ну хорошо. Недостатков я вижу три штуки:
1) Производительность. Тут как-никак регексп.
2) Нет параметра $length
3) Изобретеный велосипед. Уж не знаю что за ерунда на скриншоте, но функции mb_ вполне нормальные сами по себе.

Comment: на скриншоте то, что и есть - результат работы mb_substr. Точно такое же чудо выводит и сама subsrt.

Comment: http://subcoder.ru/mb.php
вот реальный пример. кодировка UTF-8,  полный код страницы
><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><?
echo mb_substr('здесь пишем какой то текст',0,20);
?></body></html>

Так чем же плох мой код?

Answer (score 3):

У функции mb_substr есть четвертый параметр. У меня вызов

```
<? echo mb_substr('здесь пишем какой то текст',0,20,'UTF-8'); ?>
```

работает вполне адекватно, в то время как вызов

```
<? echo mb_substr('здесь пишем какой то текст',0,20); ?>
```

дает результат, аналогичный substr. Видимо 'internal character encoding' в моей сборке PHP (так же как судя по всему и в Вашей) отличается от UTF-8.

Что касается собственно приведенной Вами функции, то такая постановка вопроса ставит в тупик. Что значит "чем плоха"? А Вас самого что в ней смущает, кроме собственно производительности?

Comment: Просто эту функцию я нашел на сайте php.net, она прекрасно помогла в моей ситуации, я выложил ее на своем блоге, после чего получил анонимный комментарий оскорбительного характера, дескать, я настолько идиот, что моченьки нет, что использую ЭТО. Поскольку, у меня нет возможности лично поприветствовать данного индивида, и спросить у его лица - почему же я настолько неправ, хочу узнать об этом от вас. Действительно ли данная функция настолько хреновая, что из-за этого стоит написать кучу оскорбительных выражений человеку, или просто мир сошел сума?

Comment: Если рассматривать в таком ракурсе, то все недостатки перечислил Dmitri Kadykov в комментариях к предыдущему ответу. И на самом деле то, что mb_substr не работает без четвертого параметра, лично для меня явилось неожиданностью.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.